# Why am I getting "database is locked"?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am getting an error "database is locked" on SQlite version 3.7.11, which means two or more incompatible operations are happening on the same database.
I tried Googling for "sqlite database is locked"  and "file locking and concurrency in SQLite version 3", but I cannot figure out the reason behind this.

The Sqlite3 APIs are encapsulated by the following function (in pseudocode):

```
int dbClass::ExecSql(char *sql)
{
    gisLONG rtn=0;
    CHECK_PTRVAL(m_dbHandle)
        if(sql==NULL)
        {
            rtn=SQLITE_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            CloseCursor();
            rtn=local_sqlite3_prepare_v2((sqlite3 *)m_dbHandle,sql,-1,(sqlite3_stmt **)&m_pStmt,NULL);
        }

        if (rtn==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            rtn=sqlite3_step((sqlite3_stmt *)m_pStmt);
            if (rtn==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                m_bFirst=false;
                m_curPos=1;
                rtn=1;
            }
            else if(rtn==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                m_curPos=-1;
                rtn=1;
            }
            else
            {
                rtn=0;
            }
            return(rtn);
        }

        int errcode=sqlite3_errcode((sqlite3 *)m_dbHandle);
        errcode=sqlite3_extended_errcode((sqlite3 *)m_dbHandle);

        return (0);
}


bool TableExist(string tblName)
{
    string sql = "select name from sqlite_master where type='table' and name=";
    sql += tblName;

    ExecSql(sql);   // a function executes sql language

    return RowCount() > 0;  // counts of result by "select" sql
}

long CreateTableInner(string tblName, string fieldList)
{
    if (!TableExist())
    {
        string sql = "create table ";
        sql += tblName + fieldList;

        return ExecSql(sql);
    }
}

long CreateBlobTableInner(string tblName)
{
    if (!TableExist())
    {
        string sql = "create table ";
        sql += tblName;
        sql += "blob";
        sql += " (id INT, classname BLOB)";

        return ExecSql(sql);
    }
}

void CreateTable(short type)
{
    if (type == 1)
    {
        CreateTableInner("cache", "length INT, start INT");
        CreateTableInner("path", "name BLOB");
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        CreateTableInner("dot", "id INT, name BLOB");
        CreateBlobTableInner("dot);

        CreateTableInner("line", "id INT, name BLOB");
        CreateBlobTableInner("line");
    }
}

OutFunction(short type)
{
    OpenA(fileName, type);  // it calls sqlite3_open_v2(), then do nothing
    CreateTable(type);
}
```

A.dll calls OutFunction(1);
when all tables exist, OutFunction() just opens x.db file. When B.exe invokes A.dll opening, x.db cannot be modified.
if CreateTable() is commented out, all is ok and x.db can be changed.

can anyone find the reason?

Comment: Are you sure only one program at a time has access to the database?  SQLite can have issues with concurrency.  Please see [their documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) on the topic.

Comment: There is some other active transaction. Show the implementation of `ExecSql`.

Comment: @GiagaWatt, yes, only one process when database locked and i have read the document

Comment: @CL, attach it in the answer...

Comment: Probably there is some other active transaction, possibly explicit, possibly implicit.  This can be due to multiple threads hitting the DB at once, a single thread forgetting to appropriately end a transaction or finalize a statement, or the accidental "nesting" of transactions.  (I notice that the above code doesn't appear to guarantee that the prepared statement is finalized before the next one is started.)

Comment: Are you ever calling `sqlite3_finalize`?

Comment: @Hot Licks, yes, **there is some other active transaction**. i can convince that only one process opened DB by nirSoft_OpendFilesView. and A.exe is just a single process.

Comment: @CL. I tried add `sqlite3_finalize` before `return(rtn)`. now db file first is opened by A.exe, then B.exe, it can be insert, delete. when db files is opened by A.exe, then A.exe, nothing can do with db file.

Comment: The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) is not fantastic, but it's pretty good.  I'd suggest you spend some time getting to know it.  You may want to read about [atomic commit](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).

Comment: Note that "active transaction" does not necessarily mean that another thread is accessing the DB.  Rather, it can mean that you've started a transaction in one method and then are attempting to start a second in a different method.  This gets confounded if you open the DB each time you access it, vs opening it once for the app and leaving it open.

Comment: @HotLicks, er, i have read [Atomic Commit In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html), [Database Is Locked](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) and [File Locking And Concurrency](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).  and i will check all methods. and finnally, thanks for you patience.